# Adobe Air HtmlLoader - quietly failing

Tags: air

Hi I am trying to load page into Air using the htmlLoader class. What event listener will I need to attach to the HTMLLoader class in order for it to notify me when the page can not be loaded.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: I've used a timer for the time being and everything seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

The only event fired directly from the HTMLLoader that appears to be error handling is:

uncaughtScriptException
Signals that an uncaught JavaScript exception occurred in the HTMLLoader object.

however when you call send and pass along a URLRequest you should be able to add listeners to the Loader, from an example in the docs, this should be good enough:

```
        dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, openHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
```

in your case I'm guessing you'll need to use the HTMLLoader instance's loaderInfo property and add the listeners there.

Hope this helps.